# one to many mapping in hibernate spring mvc +jsp

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp, hibernate-mapping

I want to use hibernate one-to-many mapping for spring mvc web application.I have two entity classes Project and Site.

```
    Class Project{

private String pid;
........
protected Set<Site> site;

//getter and setter

}

Class Site{

private String siteid;
private String name;
.................
//getter and setter
}
```

My question is how to add multiple site for one project in jsp. and save to both table at a time.How to achieve this in jsp.

Answer (score 0):

First you can map these two classes by hibernate mappings like below.

Project.java

```
public class Project{
private String pid;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="project",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Site> site;

//getter and setter
}
```

Site.java

```
public class Site{
private String siteid;
private String name;
@ManyToOne
private Project project;
.................
//getter and setter
}
```

*how to add multiple site for one project in jsp* :

from JSP you can have one multiple select dropdown by passing the id of sites and save to server.

*save to both table at a time* :

That cascade type will do for you.